# Why do I get "javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException" when the path exists on AEM?

Tags: java, aem, jcr

I am trying to copy node tree of a template to a node named "root" like the following:

```
Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace();
workspace.copy(templatePath + "/initial/jcr:content/root", contentNode.getPath() + "/root");    
Node rootNode = contentNode.getNode("root");
```

templatePath is the string to template. I am trying to copy "/initial/jcr:content/root" under the template path and paste it to child node named "root" under the node contentNode.
I ran the code above and got **javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException** on the last line. When I went to CrxDe on AEM, the node tree has been copied and pasted, and the path actually exists although I got the error message. I tried to add

```
  session.save();
```

After I copied. But the same error persisted although the nodes exists and have been copied.

What is causing it?

Comment: "AEM", as in "Adobe Experience Cloud" (I had to google that)?

Comment: Adobe Experience Manager

Comment: No need for `Session#save` after `Workspace#copy` because it does not operate on a session and changes are applied immediately. The `contentNode` you have, however, is part of the current session so it might not be up-to-date (or it caches its list of children). If `Session#refresh` doesn’t help, just try resolving the node again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `session.save()`, try adding a `session.refresh()` before you use `contentNode` again.